# Norm of a real function

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

Given a function $g:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ which is nonnegative, suppose we take any norm of this function. Is it true to say

$$\Vert g(x)\Vert =\vert g(x) \vert = g(x)?$$

Additionally,

If we have a matrix $K\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and a vector $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$. For any norm do we have that

$$\big\Vert\Vert Kx\Vert\big\Vert = \Vert Kx\Vert$$

Comment: What norm?  Normally, for a function $g$, we denote the norm $\|g\|$ which does not depend on $x$ but only on $g$.  Examples of norms are things like in the $L^p$ spaces, $\|g\|_p = \left(\int |g|^pd\mu\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}$.  You have $\|g\|$ is a real number which doesn't depend on $x$, while $g$ is a function, and $g(x)$ is a real number which does depend on $x$.

Comment: Suppose we are given $x$, when taking the norm $\Vert g(x)\Vert$ we are just taking the norm of a real number $g(x)\in\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Keep in mind, there are many *different* norms.  You will need to specify which norms you are referring to, otherwise the answer in general is a definite no.  You can have $\|1\|_a \neq \|1\|_b$ with two different norms $\|~\|_a$ and $\|~\|_b$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, we have $g(x) \in \mathbb{R}$.
And as $g$ is nonnegative, we have $g(x) \ge 0$, and so $|g(x)| = g(x)$.
However, given any $a >0$, we have a norm $\| \cdot \|_a$ on $\mathbb{R}$ by $\| x \|_a = a| x|$, so it is not true that $\| g(x) \| = | g(x)|$ without specifying the norm on $\mathbb{R}$.